# How does banner selection work with so many variables? (Advertising server)

Tags: database, banner-ads, advertisement-server

I know that when i view a webpage a request is made to the advertising server and they know my ip/preferences. But how does the banner selection work since there are so many variables like geotargeting . Do they query for a banner and try to compare the variables from the request and from the banner and if not equal get another banner and retry till success. For example:

1. Ad request user is from Italy.
2. Get random banner add. Banner has only USA in allowed countries.
3. Get another banner . This user has seen this banner today.
4. Get another banner. This banner can only work only at certan times or days.
5. Get another. Success. Display banner and track.

Or do they use some magical query?

Thanks.

Comment: This is so entirely network dependant. This will get downvoted unless you provide specifics.

Comment: I want to know about the database queries

Answer (score 0):

NO, you would not keep making random requests. You'd take the data from the user/ip/eviltrackingcookie whatever and pass it to the server to do a database query for the given parameters you need to fulfill. Then the server would respond with the proper ad.

Comment: but how does it get general banners, who have for example All countries allowed?

Answer (score 0):

An Ad server is a the brain of Advertising . they are made with so many of experiments . The major role is played by the cookies here plus your IP address , The cookies having all the relevant data for showing up you the Ad . As the request goes from your browser to the server all the relevant parameters are matched in some less than a second to show up the right Ad.

Comment: That's a whole bunch of nonsense.